# I cant get print when expression to work on a border. iReports 2.0.5

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a frame around a group of text fields (name & address).  I have defined a border in the frame.  I only want to print the border during certain situations but the border is printing all the time.  I have the following code in the print when: new Boolean("PO".indexOf($F{type}) > -1).
So what I want is if "type" starts with "PO", I want to print the border.  If it does not start with "PO", dont print the border.  Again, the border is printing regardless of what is in "type".

Comment: You can use conditional style or show one of two textFields or hide frame with *printWhenExpression*

Comment: How do I hide frame?